# Calendar Event In Outlook Cuts Off After New Line

Tags: outlook, calendar, icalendar

I'm trying to generate calendar events to load in various programs, and this code works in Google Calendars, but when I generate an ICS and open it in Outlook, all the text in the description field after the first paragraph gets cut off.

Original:

> Student Wellness, the Students' Association and the Heart & Stroke
>   Foundation are utilizing the memorable Jump Rope for Heart event for
>   our Campus community to raise awareness about physical activity,
>   mental health and our onsite campus resources. Receive a terrific
>   opportunity to learn about the Heart & Stroke Foundation, Campus
>   Activities & Mental Health, and help raise dollars for the Foundation.
>
> Many Activity Challenges and prizes will also be there for some fun
>   and excitment.
>
> For more information contact - wellness@gprc.ab.ca; 780-539-2436 ​OR
>   Visit the Event Webpage by CLICKING HERE

In Outlook:

> Student Wellness, the Students' Association and the Heart & Stroke
>   Foundation are utilizing the memorable Jump Rope for Heart event for
>   our Campus community to raise awareness about physical activity,
>   mental health and our onsite campus resources. Receive a terrific
>   opportunity to learn about the Heart & Stroke Foundation, Campus
>   Activities & Mental Health, and help raise dollars for the Foundation.

Code:

```
    var myCalendar = createCalendar({
        options: {
            class: 'my-class'
        },
        data: {
            title: '<?php echo $event_title ?>',     // Event title
            start: new Date('<?= $row['start_date'] .' '. $row['start_time'] ?>'),   // Event start date
            duration: 120,                            // Event duration (IN MINUTES)
            end: new Date('<?= $row['end_date'] .' '. $row['end_time'] ?>'),     // You can also choose to set an end time. If an end time is set, this will take precedence over duration
            address: 'https://www.gprc.ab.ca<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] .'?'. $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ?>',
            description: '<?= str_replace(["'"], '’', str_replace(['\\n\\n\\n\\n'], '\\n\\n', str_replace(['&amp;'], '＆', str_replace(['<br>','<br />',"\r\n","\x0D"], "\\n", strip_tags ( autoLinker($event_content), '<br><br />' ))))); ?>'
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are not escaping newlines in the iCalendar data.  Newlines are encoded as ´\n´.